# Pie Chart applet not showing up in browser

Tags: java

I'm trying to get the pie chart drawing of my java applet to show up but only the text is showing up. I've checked my code and the html and nothing seems off. Here is my code if it helps:

Java File:

```
package org.me.pie;

import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class PieChart extends Applet
{

    /**
     * Initialization method that will be called after the applet is loaded into
     * the browser.
     */
    @Override
    public void init() 
    {

    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {

        // source: http://www.rasmussenreports.com/public_content/politics/obama_administration/daily_presidential_tracking_poll


        // approval + disapproval percentages
        int approve    = 46;
        int disapprove = 53;

        int total;

        // add up the approval and disapproval
        total = approve + disapprove;


        float approvePercent = (approve * 100.0f) / total; // percent who approve
        float disapprovePercent = (disapprove * 100.0f) / total; // percent who disapprove


        int x = 250, y = 50, w = 200, h = 200; // size of the pie chart

        int startAngle, degrees; // used to draw a pie slice


        // draw the approval slice
        startAngle = 0;
        degrees = (int)(approvePercent * 360 / 100);

        g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        g.fillArc(x, y, w, h, startAngle, degrees);



        // draw the disapproval slice
        startAngle  += degrees;
        degrees = (int)(disapprovePercent * 360 / 100);

        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.fillArc(x, y, w, h, startAngle, degrees);



        // draw the strings for color codes on who approves and disapproves
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);

        g.setFont(new Font("TimesRoman", Font.BOLD, 16));
        g.drawString("Yellow - Approve", 20, 80);

        g.drawString("Red - Disapprove", 20, 100);

        super.paint(g);
    }
}
```

And the html:

```
   <!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Applet</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <object type="application/x-java-applet" width="200" height="400">
                <param name="code" value="org.me.pie.PieChart"> 
                <param name="archive" value="Week4.jar">
                Applet failed to run.  No Java plug-in was found.
            </object>  

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

[image][image]

As you can see, it runs fine in the applet viewer in netbeans but does not load in the browser. Any help would be appreciated :).

Comment: Which Firefox version are you on?

Comment: I'm running version 37.0.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this

```
<object type="application/x-java-applet" width="200" height="400">
```

to something like this

```
<object type="application/x-java-applet" width="800" height="600">
```

Visible area is w=200 h=400, but the circle seems to be drawn outside of this visible area.

To be clear, with the inserted values you're drawing the circle like this

```
g.fillArc(250, 50, 200, 200, startAngle, degrees);
```

Minimal width should be x + width (250 + 200). The minimal height should be  y + height (50 + 200).